# Git clone not coping in to WORKDIR [ Dockerfile ]

Tags: docker, docker-compose

while building a docker image - RUN git clone rep@rep.com is working. But i can't able to move the exact **app.py** in to  WORKDIR (Dockerfile), which is in the git repo.

you can see my git [repo](https://github.com/testgithub-trial/docktest.git) & can chek it with my **Dockerfile**. please correct me if I am wrong

- (If my Dockerfile is wrong please rechange )

> **Need Like:**  it have to clone only *app.py* from git repo to continer-WORKDIR.

***Here is My Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl


RUN git clone https://github.com/testgithub-trial/docktest.git
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD /docktest /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


COPY . .


CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

**Here is my Folder structure.** (***Note:*** *requirement.txt* will be locally present (not in git repo)

[image: Here is my Folder structure]

**Here is my Output Terminal.**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3
 ---> e2e732b7951f
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     locales     zip     jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle     vim     unzip     git     curl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93a0e5877ac6
Step 3/9 : RUN git clone https://github.com/testgithub-trial/docktest.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36313099edf8
Step 4/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35c1e7a26f44
Step 5/9 : ADD /docktest /usr/src/app
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat docktest: file does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to `RUN mv /docktest /usr/src/app`. `ADD` is for files in the build context (your machine), not ones in the image itself

Comment: Bro , this time image is creating but, when i am running it it showing  ` python: can't open file '/usr/src/app/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory `. do i need to  change CMD in dockerfile?? can u have a look on it bro.

Comment: That's because it's probably `/usr/src/app/docktest/app.py`

Comment: Thanks bro, working fine